# When you define operators as datatype in SML, do they act as functions as operators?

Tags: sml, smlnj

When you define operators as datatype in SML, do they act as functions as operators?

like `datatype egexp= egadd of egexp*egexp`

does egadd act as operator or function? I mean do I write the expression a+b as egadd(a)(b) or (a)egadd(b)?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write neither. It acts on a "function" (actually, as a value constructor), taking the types you specified.

That is, since you specified that `egadd` takes an `egexp * egexp`, it takes a tuple of two `egexps`, that is: `egadd (a, b)`, where `a` and `b` are values of the type `egexp`.

If desired, you can make it infix like any other function by using `infix` or `infixr`.

Answer (score 4):

You are essentially asking about infix syntax. This actually has nothing to do with functions vs constructors, both can either be infix or (by default) nonfix:

```
fun f (x, y) = ...
val a = f (1, 2)
infix f
val b = 1 f 2

datatype t = C of int * int
val c = C (1, 2)
infix C
val d = 1 C 2
```

This applies uniformly to alphanumeric and symbolic identifiers:

```
fun ++ (x, y) = ...
val a = ++ (1, 2)
infix ++
val b = 1 ++ 2

datatype t = && of int * int
val c = && (1, 2)
infix &&
val d = 1 && 2
```

That is, there is no distinction between 'functions' and 'operators' in SML. You just have nonfix vs infix identifiers.

Comment: How come the syntax seems to allow the special `op` prefix when defining such a symbolic constructor name `datatype t = op&& of int * int`. What's the point of that syntax?

Comment: @xyz, no real point, it's always redundant. I suppose it's just allowed so that you can uniformly write `op+` and so on in all places.

Answer (score 0):

`egadd` is a "constructor". `egexp` is an *algebraic data type*, and `egadd` is one of its constructors. Constructors in SML can either have no arguments, or one argument (multiple "components" can be packed into 1 tuple argument). As a constructor with an argument, `egadd` is also a function that takes an argument of that argument type (`egexp*egexp`) and returns ("constructs") a value of the algebraic data type `egexp`. For example, as @SebastianPaaskeTørho mentioned, if `a` and `b` are values of type `egexp`, then `egadd (a, b)` constructs a new value of type `egexp`.